# Silly Check My Short Beginners Code Question

Tags: python

I want to run the following:

```
import sys

f = open("results.txt", "w+")

for n in range(1, 100000):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        if(i**2 % n ==2):
            counter = counter+1
    print('There are', counter, 'solutions in Z_',n,'Short', counter,'in', n, file=f )

f.close()
```

But program breaks too early e.g. on 30227. 
And I can't figure out why.

> EDIT: Then I added print(n) after the first "for" that is changed as follows:

```
import sys

f = open("results.txt", "w+")

for n in range(1, 100000):
    print(n)
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        if(i**2 % n ==2):
            counter = counter+1
    print('There are', counter, 'solutions in Z_',n,'Short', counter,'in', n, file=f )

f.close()
```

And received a file with all 100 000 rows as I wanted.

Then I tried to evaluate the initial code and again received a file with last rows

```
There are 2 solutions in Z_ 5783 Short 2 in 5783
There are 0 solutions in Z_
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You don't get any error message?

Comment: What are the contents of file after execution?

Comment: Now I have added print(n) after first for and am waiting for termination. 
There were lines "There are $x$ solutions in Z_$n$ Short $x$ in $n$. where $x$ is a number of solutions of $x^2=2$ in $\mathbb Z_n$. And in file were 30227 lines instead of 100 000 lines as I wanted.

Comment: An unlikely cause, but do you have enough free disk space for the file?

Comment: @VPfB :D Yes, sure.

Comment: I added some additional results.

Comment: the original code works as intended.

Comment: It works for me too. I have no other explanation except that some kind of resource limit is stopping your program.

Comment: Yea, it seems something with in my windows does this, but what can it be. with printing in consol it does work and without printing in consol do not :(

Comment: I'm a Linux guy, cannot help with Windows.